# Why is the value of this variable undefined

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning javascript and came across this example

```
var t = function()
{
  this.name = "Jam";
  no = "123";
}

console.log(t.no); //Undefined 
var m = new t();
console.log(m.name);
```

Why is the first statement undefined ?

Comment: Because `t` is function, not an object.

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen - Functions *are* objects.

Comment: @nnnnnn I should've been more specific. What I intended to say is that in order to access the properties of `function` `t` you would need to instantiate it (i.e, turn it into an `object`).

Comment: No, `t` is *already* an object that can have its own properties without any need to instantiate any other objects. `t.no= "123"` creates a property on `t` itself (the OP tried to access such a property without creating it).

Comment: @nnnnnn Oh okay, thanks. I had misunderstood the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`t` is a function object.  As any other object, the function may have properties assigned. So in order your code to work you shall assign `"123"` to `no` property of your function (line A):

```
var t = function()
{
  this.name = "Jam";
}
t.no = "123"; // line A

console.log(t.no); // "123"
var m = new t();
console.log(m.name);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the first statement undefined ?

Because `t` doesn't have a property `no`.

First of all, the code *inside* the function, namely

```
this.name = "Jam";
no = "123";
```

is only executed when the function is *called*. You are doing this with `var m = new t();`, which comes *after* `console.log(t.no);`.

Secondly, `no = "123";` *does not* create a property on the function object. It will attempt to set the value of variable `no`. Since the variable doesn't exist in your example, that line will either create a *global variable* `no`, or throw in error if your code is in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Consider the following example:

```
var no = 21;
function foo() {
  no = 42;
}
console.log(no); // 21
foo();
console.log(no); // 42
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `t` is a function, that would be executed by `t();`. `no` on the other hand is a global scooed variable that is reached without prefix from everywhere.

Comment: "`no` on the other hand is an internal variable" it appears from the example that `no` is an implicit global variable, given the lack of `var`, `let`, or `const` keywords.

Comment: I actually realized it is even worse. 'no' isn't declared with "var" in front, so it is now a GLOBAL variable. Never do that or bad things will happen! ;)

Comment: @zzzzBov yes, no is not part of t. You reach it without prefix.

Answer (score 1):

`t` is a function expression. You you can access a returned object of a function like `t().no` or you can create a new object by using the function as a constructor like this

```
myT = new t()
console.log(t.no);
```

But your `no` variable is just a global variable inside the function and it is not a part of what it returns nor it is not attached to the returning object of the constructor function.

[Here](http://helephant.com/2008/08/17/how-javascript-objects-work/) is a very good tutorial which covers all these topics at depths.

Comment: As commented under my own answer, no is actually *not* private, but *globally* scoped.. Bad code can be tricky to read.. :)

Comment: *"your `no` variable is just a private variable"* - That variable is global (because it wasn't declared with `var`).