# Can a function constructor contain non-this variable?

Tags: javascript

I noticed that if I create something like this

```
var j = function(){
 this.name = "Joe",
 var no = "23" //--->statement 2
}
```

I get the error 
 var no = "23"
 ^^^

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token var
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([stdin]-wrapper:6:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at node.js:328:29
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

I understand that a function constructor should use "this" with variables but I am curious as to why I get an error at statement 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you mean this instead?

```
var j = function(){
 this.name = "Joe";
 var no = "23";
}
```

Notice the semicolon instead of comma after "Joe".  That semicolon is optional anyway.  You can leave it out.

Comment: also could you explain why adding `j();
console.log(j.no);` returns undefined ?

Comment: Because `no` isn't a preperty of `j`, it's a variable inside constructor that's not available from outside.

Comment: How do i know if its a property ?

Comment: @JamesFranco You've asked this question before. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234895/why-is-the-value-of-this-variable-undefined).

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen yeah looks like i need to read a little more. It gets confusing. And people said Javascript isnt confusing at all

Comment: It really isn't confusing, once you get a hang of it :)

Comment: @JamesFranco, if you do `this.no = "23"` instead, it will become a property.  `var` declares your variable *only inside the score of the constructor*.  Nobody else from the outside will see it. Doing `this.no = "23"` exposes it to anyone outside.

Comment: @SaeedJahed thanks for clearing that up - Marked as answer

Comment: @JamesFranco, one more note.  If you're using a constructor function you need to do `var x = new j()` instead.  Notice the keywoard "new".  Then your x will have the properties you're looking for.